# Calculating bi-weekly development of tickets in dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need some help. My data set looks currently like this:

```
Date    Ticket (1/0)        Week number
01.07.2020       0      1
01.07.2020       1      1
01.07.2020       1      1
01.07.2020       0      1
15.07.2020       0      2
15.07.2020       0      2
15.07.2020       0      2
01.08.2020       1      3
01.08.2020       1      3
01.08.2020       0      3
01.08.2020       0      3
01.08.2020       1      3
```

The end result that I need should be something like this:

```
Date                  01.07.2020    15.07.2020      01.08.2020
Development of tickets     2          -2                1
```

I need the end matrix to sum the tickets in that week and substract the tickets of the previous week from it. How do I achieve that? How should the measure look like?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: In your data set, what's the difference between [Date] and [Week] apart from data type? Is there a cardinality difference? Also you should use a dim table, you don't need to but from a performance point of view it's better. In your desired outcome I don't understand the final value, according to your description this should be 3-0 = 3 but you seem to have calculated 3-2 = 1.

Comment: Week is the week number. And yes sorry I may have misexplained it but it should be 3-2=1, and then week 4 would be the tickets from week 4 minus 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Let your table name is - **your_table_name**

Now create a new table **new_table_name** using this below code-

```
let
    Source = your_table_name,
    #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(#"Source",".","-",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Date"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Replaced Value",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type1", {"Date", "Week number"}, {{"sum_tickets", each List.Sum([#"Ticket (1/0)"]), type nullable number}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each [Week number] + 1),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom", {"Week number"}, #"Added Custom", {"Custom"}, "Added Custom", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Added Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Custom", {"sum_tickets"}, {"Added Custom.sum_tickets"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Expanded Added Custom",{{"Week number", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Sorted Rows", "Final_Total", each [sum_tickets] - [Added Custom.sum_tickets]),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"sum_tickets", "Custom", "Added Custom.sum_tickets"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```

This is the table output-

[image]

**Now** add a matrix visual and add Date to Column field and Final_total to the Values field. The output will be as below-

[image]